# Black seams in stitched image generated by Python and OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, panoramas, image-stitching

```
(ret,data_map) = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(next_img_warp, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
(ret_base,data_map_base) = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(base_img_warp, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

firstly I converted two images to grayscale.Then I use `cv2.bitwise_and()` to get the mask of the overlapping part.

```
mask =cv2.bitwise_and(data_map,data_map_base)
inv_mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
```

then I used the mask to get three parts:

```
base_cross = cv2.add(base, base_img_warp, mask=mask, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
next_cross = cv2.add(base, next_img_warp, mask=mask, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
base_not_cross = cv2.add(base, base_img_warp, mask=inv_mask, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
next_not_cross = cv2.add(base, next_img_warp, mask=inv_mask, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
```

`base` is a black base image.

then I do linear blending using `base_cross` and `next_cross` and get the blended overlapping part `cross_blend  =self.blendImage(base_cross,next_cross)`

finally I put the three parts back together using `cv2.add` and the mask:

```
base_not_cross = cv2.add(enlarged_base_img, base_img_warp, mask=inv_mask, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
next_not_cross = cv2.add(enlarged_base_img, next_img_warp, mask=inv_mask, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
final_img =  cv2.add(base_not_cross, next_not_cross, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
final_img =  cv2.add(final_img, cross_blend, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
```

But my question is, why I got these black seams in result images, even I put original `base_cross` or `next_cross` back instead of the blended `cross_blend`? What could I do to eliminate these black seams?
here's my result image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtiQO.jpg

Comment: Doesnt look linearly blended imho

Comment: If the images are RGBA, perhaps the warping is creating edges with partial alpha.